# Google People API / Other Contacts - how to get photos of other contacts?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-photos-api, google-people-api

Google forces us to migrate from the deprecated Contacts API over new People API.

They even implemented "Other Contacts" feature in the People API which was so demanded.

But now I'm facing another problem - there is no way to get photos of Other Contacts in the People API.

I was digging into this problem and figured out that it's possible to add `photos` into the `readMask` (even though it's not documented):

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/otherContacts?access_token=<...>&readMask=emailAddresses,names,photos
```

...but it doesn't help, because it returns the default picture with the first letter for all contacts, even for contacts who has a real photo. Like this one: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/cm/ABXenNkcRSTRZU8PEFQfJtaeEBZnxLgN-UO555npUt1idzcMohoSGuJFfKx0JX2AR6Qp=s100

I tried to add `coverPhotos` into the `readMask` but it doesn't let it there.

Then I was checking how old Contacts API formats photo urls and figured out the format:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/<user-email-address>/<contact-id>
```

But it has 2 disadvantages:

- this url has to be requested with `access_token`
- it works only if the contact uploaded a custom photo, otherwise it returns error

So here is my question:

**Is there any simpler and cleaner way to get real photos of Other Contacts in People API?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been solved and now we have a solution!

Updated documentation: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list

There is a new `sources[]` request parameter. To get the real photos of "other contacts" you need to specify 2 values: `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT` and `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE`.

The request would look like this:

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/otherContacts?readMask=photos&key=API_KEY&sources=READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT&sources=READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE
```

Now some contacts will contain 2 entries in the `photos` array:

```
photos: [
  {
    metadata: {
      primary: true,
      source: {
        type: "PROFILE",
        id: "11111"
      }
    },
    url: "<THIS IS THE REAL PROFILE PICTURE>"
  },
  {
    metadata: {
      source: {
        type: "OTHER_CONTACT",
        id: "6666666"
      }
    },
    url: "<THIS IS THE DEFAULT PHOTO STUB>",
    default: true
  }
]
```

Comment: This is helpful but I'm running into a permissions error for other contact (eg: "Your client does not have permission to get URL"). How did you get around that?

Comment: Ah resolved: add scope     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

Comment: Looks like this has stopped working for the moment. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/321249335

Answer (score 0):

**The `readMask` fields accepted for the `otherContacts.list` method are the following:**

- `emailAddresses`
- `metadata`
- `names`
- `phoneNumbers`
- `photos`

As you can notice, the `photos` field is an accepted one while making the above request.

However, the returned response should yield a url which redirects you to the user's profile picture. Because of this, I have taken the opportunity to report it on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/193647341). I suggest you star the issue as any updates regarding this will be posted there.

#### Reference

- [People API otherContacts.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list);
- [People API Support](https://developers.google.com/people/support).

Comment: Awesome! I marked it too. I have a strong feeling that yesterday in the docs `photos` was absent among accepted values for `readMask`